# Does waitpid blocks on a stopped job?

Tags: unix, process

I have a child process which has received a SIGTSTP signal.
When I call

```
waitpid(-1,NULL,0);
```

the parent blocks, but in documentation, its written that waitpid returns with pid for stopped jobs.

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
main() {
int pid;
if( (pid=fork()) > 0) {
    sleep(5);
    if(kill(pid,SIGTSTP) < 0)
        printf("kill error\n");
    int status;
    waitpid(-1,&status,0);
    printf("Returned %d\n",WIFSTOPPED(status));
}
else if(pid==0) {
    while(1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the option `WUNTRACED` for `waitpid` (3rd argument). Otherwise it doesn't return until the job is terminated.

When the `WUNTRACED` option is set, children of the current process that are stopped due to a `SIGTTIN`, `SIGTTOU`, `SIGTSTP`, or `SIGSTOP` signal also have their status reported (from the mac man page).

Comment: Thank u very much for ur answer. I should have read the documentaion properly. I wasted two hours in my large program looking for other errors.